# what are the memory impacts of increasing a NIC's ring buffer?

Tags: linux, nic, performance-tuning

What impact (if any) does NIC ring buffer tuning (e.g. via `ethtool -G eth0 …`) have on system memory utilization? For example, does increasing the ring buffer consume more RAM? And if so, how much? Or is the memory required for the "maximum" value already always preallocated — for example, in hardware?